# 'OSError : Out of pty devices' with Ansible Tower on CentOS7

Tags: python, ansible, centos7, pty, ansible-tower

I installed ansible tower on CentOS 7. I try to run a playbook but I get the following error every time:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 147, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 620, in _execute
    self._connection = self._get_connection(cvars, templar)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 957, in _get_connection
    socket_path = start_connection(self._play_context, options, self._task._uuid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 1124, in start_connection
    master, slave = pty.openpty()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pty.py", line 29, in openpty
    master_fd, slave_name = _open_terminal()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pty.py", line 70, in _open_terminal
    raise os.error, 'out of pty devices'
OSError: out of pty devices
fatal: [SW1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", 
    "stdout": ""
}
```

I also tested by changing the virtual execution environment and it still does not work.

```
task path: /tmp/bwrap_10_czq13qv4/awx_10_5t93z8ow/project/01_test.yml:2
<10.1.16.190> attempting to start connection
<10.1.16.190> using connection plugin network_cli
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/my-envs/custom-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 147, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/opt/my-envs/custom-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 620, in _execute
    self._connection = self._get_connection(cvars, templar)
  File "/opt/my-envs/custom-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 957, in _get_connection
    socket_path = start_connection(self._play_context, options, self._task._uuid)
  File "/opt/my-envs/custom-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 1124, in start_connection
    master, slave = pty.openpty()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/pty.py", line 29, in openpty
    master_fd, slave_name = _open_terminal()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/pty.py", line 59, in _open_terminal
    raise OSError('out of pty devices')
OSError: out of pty devices
fatal: [S1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

I tried to launch the playbook manually without using Ansible Tower with the "ansible-playbook" command and it works.

I followed the instructions from the following sites:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/upgrade-migration-guide/virtualenv.html#preparing-a-new-custom-virtualenv
- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4371201

I also searched on other forums I did not find other people who had the same problem as me on Ansible Tower. Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Since Ansible Tower has Python 3 as [Requirement](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/installandreference/requirements_refguide.html), maybe ['OSError : Out of pty devices' on Centos 7.5 for non-root users](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2224) will help to find a solution.

Comment: I've already tried it and it doesn't change anything. Even using a non-root user with the example command works `python -c "import pty; pty.fork()"`. I just have the problem on Ansible Tower

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
This is from version 3.8.5 of Ansible Tower.
If you have the same problem come back to a later version.
I will notify Red Hat support